# How to check mongodb path where if store the data

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Using ubuntu 14.04, I want to change my mongodb path from current to default:

```
/var/lib/mongodb
```

I have made some changes by using `dbpath=/data/db` command but I don't remember the exact path. So the problem is my mongodb data there in `var/lib/mongodb` but I am not able to access data as I have changed the path so I can create database on some other path but not able to access my current data which is stored in `var/lib/mongodb`.

Can anyone please tell me the way so I can access that data again.

I've checked in `mongod.conf` file

```
storage:
  dbPath: /var/lib/mongodb
```

I've tried setting `dbpath=/var/lib/mongodb`, but it didn't worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

problem solved by following command.

`sudo mongod --port 27017 --dbpath /var/lib/mongodb/`